# How to create unique URIs in Spring Data REST repositories?

Tags: java, spring-data-rest

I face a smilar scenario to this one. Let's have classic many-to-many relationship:

```
public class Student {
  private Long id;

  private String name;

  private List<StudentCourse> studentCourses = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

and

```
public class Course {
  private Long id;

  private String name;

  private List<StudentCourse> studentCourses = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Course subscriptions are managed by this:

```
public class StudentCourse {
  private Long id;

  private Student student;

  private Course course;
}
```

### The situation

The representation for a `Student` entity retrieved via the API looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "Peter",
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "myapiroot/api/students/1"
        },
        "studentCourses": {
            "href": "myapiroot/api/students/1/studentCourses"
        }
    }
}
```

The representation of a `Course` entity looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "Engineering",
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "myapiroot/api/courses/1"
        },
        "studentCourses": {
            "href": "myapiroot/api/courses/1/studentCourses"
        }
    }
}
```

A `StudentCourse` entity retrieved from the API looks like this:

```
{
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "myapiroot/api/studentCourses/1"
        },
        "student": {
            "href": "myapiroot/api/studentCourses/1/student"
        },
        "course": {
            "href": "myapiroot/api/studentCourses/1/course"
        },            
    }
}
```

### What I want to achieve

If I already have a course in memory (with a `self` URI), I want to be able to determine the course from the `StudentCourse` representation without having to navigate to the `course` URI. I want to be able to treat the `course` URI inside the `StudentCourse` representation like a foreign key in a database - a unique identifier. Since every representation has a `self` URI, I want that unique identifier to be that.

### The problem

I see no way compare equality between two entities from different sources. The URI for both student and course in the `StudentCourse` representation is *not* equal to the `self` link in the `Student` and `Course` representations.

Since IDs are not exported by default, how can I effectively determine that two different instances of the same type, acquired from different routes in the API, are equal?

#### Example:

I have a `Student` entity from `myapiroot/api/students/1`.

I have a `Course` entity from `myapiroot/api/courses/1`.

I want to find out if that student is subscribed to that course. For this I have to make the following steps:

1. Navigate to `myapiroot/api/students/1/studentCourses` to get all of the student's course subscriptions.
2. Make an additional request for each of the student's course subscriptions to `myapiroot/studentCourses/{id}/course` to retrieve the course instances.
3. Compare the course URIs with the `self` URI from the known course entity.

That second step is horribly inefficient and could be totally avoided if the course URI in the `StudentCourse` representation were equal to the `self` link of the course entity I already know.

### My first approach

I have tried to customize the resource returned by the `StudentCourseRepository` by implementing a custom `StudentCourseResourceProcessor` like this:

```
public class StudentCourseResourceProcessor implements ResourceProcessor<Resource<StudentCourse>> {

  @Autowired
  private EntityLinks entityLinks;


  @Override
  public Resource<StudentCourse> process(Resource<StudentCourse> resource) {
    Student student = resource.getContent().getStudent();
    Course course = resource.getContent().getCourse();
    resource.add(entityLinks.linkToSingleResource(Student.class, student.getId()).withRel("student"));
    resource.add(entityLinks.linkToSingleResource(Course.class, course.getId()).withRel("course"));

    return resource;
  }
}
```

#### The problem with my first approach

Now the `StudentCourse` resource returned by the REST repository looks like this:

```
{
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "myapiroot/api/studentCourses/1"
        },
        "student": [
            {"href": "myapiroot/api/students/1"},
            {"href": "myapiroot/api/studentCourses/1/student"}
        ],
        "course": [
            {"href": "myapiroot/api/courses/1"},
            {"href": "myapiroot/api/studentCourses/1/course"
        ],            
    }
}
```

The `student` and `course` entries have changed from an object into an array of objects. This makes the representation of the items irregular. I have tried to remove the old links in the resource processor by calling `resource.removeLinks()` but that doesn't work. As it stands, the auto-generated URIs cannot be removed.

### My second approach

I've dug deeper into the docs and tried using [projections](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.6.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#projections-excerpts) to embed relational data in the `StudentCourse` entity representation:

```
@Projection(name="studentCourseDetails", types={StudentCourse.class})
public interface StudentCourseDetails {
  Course getCourse();
}
```

Now I can make a GET request to `myapiRoot/students/1/studentCourses?projection=studentCourseDetails`.

The `StudentCourse` representation now looks like this:

```
{
    "course": {
        "name": "Engineering"
    },
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "myapiroot/api/studentCourses/1"
        },
        "student": {
            "href": "myapiroot/api/studentCourses/1/student"
        },
        "course": {
            "href": "myapiroot/api/studentCourses/1/course"
        },            
    }
}
```

#### The problem with my second approach

The `course` information is present, however the course's `_link`s are missing. Furthermore the settings from my `ResourceProcessor` have been ignored, there is only the relational link for `course` & `student` available.

I've also learned that totally replacing those relational URIs is a bad idea, because you can perform actions on them. For example, a HTTP `PUT` to `myapiroot/studentCourses/1/course` with a body of

```
{ "href": "myapiroot/courses/2" }
```

would change the `course` association of the `StudentCourse` entity. So these relational URIs do serve a purpose!

### My questions now

- Since the relational URIs do serve a purpose, how can I uniquely identify entities coming from the REST endpoints (without having to expose the ID via a projection)?
- My first approach adds the `self` URI to the relative URI. Is this an acceptable way of handling this? What implications does this have?
- Is there an option to enable links on embedded objects inside projections (see second approach)?

Comment: Welcome to the measure once, cut twice world of Spring Data REST.

Comment: Ids can be exposed if you so require via some simple config. http://tommyziegler.com/how-to-expose-the-resourceid-with-spring-data-rest/ You can also use projections to inline linked entities within the JSON response to save the extra query.http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts.excerpting-commonly-accessed-data

Comment: At least this way I can get the ID without having to dissect URIs all the time. It doesn't help when the ID is not part of the URI though as with the `StudentCourse` link...

Comment: If you are hacking around at the URL level then you are doing something wrong. What exactly is it you want to achieve? State your problem not what you think the solution might be.http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: I think my problem has been clearly stated, but let me clear it out for you: an entity exposed by Spring Data REST does not have a unique identifier because the URIs Spring exposes are different based on where you obtained them. How can I make sure the URIs spring uses are always the `self` link and not a relative URI like `/studentCourses/{id}/student`. I agree that hacking around with URIs is far from ideal.

Comment: You are not clearing if out. What exactly is it you want to do? Forget about urls and what they might look like.  What is the question you want your api to answer in relation to student and courses.

Comment: Restructured the question to make it clearer. hope this helps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental problem is that you aren't declaring what you seek.

> I see no way compare equality between two entities from different sources.

Even if /api/courses/1 and /api/student/2/courses/3 both point at the same course, those two URIs represent different things. The first is a canonical reference to the course with no semantic overlay, while the second one represent a particular course in relation to a certain student.

It would be analogous to taking the PRIMARY KEY of the COURSES table and looking up a row of data, then comparing it to a FOREIGN KEY from the STUDENTS_COURSES table, and wondering "why aren't these two values the same?"

Another nugget that might be missing is the fact that you appear to have defined aggregate roots for all three tables, even though it's arguable you might only need two at the most, one for Student and one for Course.

> The URI for both student and course in the StudentCourse representation is not equal to the self link in the Student and Course representations.

Not it's not, because this is essentially a FOREIGN KEY in a many-to-many table, linking them together. Not until you navigate to /api/students or /api/courses can you glean the "self" link and have an absolute reference to that resource.

> I want to find out if that student is subscribed to that course

Now we're getting somewhere. THIS is the problem you're trying to solve. At a glance, you're domain model doesn't appear to depict a many-to-many relationship. Is this JPA? If so, something like this may better hint at how to do that: http://uaihebert.com/jpa-manytomany-unidirectional-and-bidirectional/

With proper modeling, you can then write queries navigating the properties. Ultimately, you should be able to take a Student and write a finder to get a list of Courses, or vice versa. And from there, you're talking about detecting the presence of a link.

Essentially, once you have Students and Courses pointing at each other via a JPA @ManyToMany relationship, you should be able to write

```
interface StudentRepository extends CrudRepository<Student,Long> {
    List<Student> findByCoursesName(@Param("q") String name);
}
```

and

```
interface CourseRepository extends CrudRepository<Course, Long>{
    List<Student> findByStudentsName(@Param("q") String name);
}
```

Check out this deck for more details: https://speakerdeck.com/olivergierke/ddd-and-rest-domain-driven-apis-for-the-web-4

Comment: Got it. Great point about the semantics of foreign keys and their meaning inside the API. I guess I was thinking too much in database terms where most of the time a foreign key equals the primary key of the referenced table (which is the implied equality I wanted to achieve with the URIs). When you interpret a foreign key more from the entity's standpoint, it makes sense.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include actual Spring Data repositories that can answer the core question.

Answer (score 2):

You have a Course and you have a Student. To find out if the student is enrolled on that course you can simply query the API. You can do this in one of two ways: by creating an explicit query method in the StudentCoursesRepository or by having this repository extend QueryDslPredicateExecutor.

Adopting the latter approach is very powerful as it allows you to query your repositories by any combination of arbitrary criteria.

```
public interface StudentCoursesRepository extends JpaRepository<StudentCourse, Long>, 
            QueryDslPredicateExecutor<StudentCuurse>{

}
```

With this in place you can now query the API as below which will return zero or 1 records:

```
http://localhost/myapiroot/api/studentCourses?
      student=http://localhost/myapiroot/api/students/1
         &course=http://localhost/myapiroot/api/courses/1
```

or, if you have exposed the ID fields and would rather deal with these:

```
http://localhost/myapiroot/api/studentCourses?student.id=1&course.id=1
```

Comment: Great point about the QueryDsl. Am I correct with my understanding that my approach using unique URIs is not possible or even undesirable? The query DSL approach would work fine when you have only one course to worry about. If you now have 100 courses you wish to analyze, you have to make 100 additional query DSL requests, which is still problematic.